# Find the domain of the functions $\sqrt {5-x} $ and $3x^2+\frac {6 } {x } -8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given the function $h(x)=\sqrt {5-x} $ and the function $f(x)=3x^2+\frac {6 } {x }  -8$ how would I find the domain without graphing?

Comment: This site uses a version of LaTeX when writing formulas. You can read about it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Nitpicking: what you are asking are the ["natural domains"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function#Natural_domain) of these formulas. For instance, $f(x)=x$ has natural domain $\mathbb{R}$ (when working with real functions). But you can restrict to, say $[0,1]$. And you get a function with domain $[0,1]$, with the same formula.

Comment: I figured it out

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$\bullet$ The **real** function $\,\sqrt x\,$ is defined *only* for $\,x\ge 0\;$ ;

$\bullet$ Rational functions (i.e. polynomial function divided by polynomial function) are defined everywhere *except* at the denominator's zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Start with all real numbers and throw away any value that causes an error (or keep the ones that do not cause an error, whichever is easier to consider).

For $\sqrt{5 - x}$, an error occurs when you try to take the square root of a negative number. The error-causing values are therefore all real numbers $x$ such that
$$
5 - x < 0.
$$

For $3x^2 + \frac{6}{x} - 8$, an error occurs when you try to divide by zero.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two functions $f$ and $G$.

Let $g$ have domain $D_g$.

Take the relational composite $g \circ f$.

Then $g \circ f$ has domain $f^{-1}[D_g]$.

So in the case of $h(x) = \sqrt{5-x}$, $h = g\circ f$, where $f(x) = 5-x$ and $g(x)=\sqrt x$.

Assuming you're dealing with real square roots, $D_g = {\uparrow}0$, so you need to solve the inequality $5-x>0$.

Comment: This answer is likely to be intimidating to someone (presumably) first learning the concept of domain.

Comment: You are right, but the other answers are excessively informal and don't get to the heart of how a function built up from pieces can be assigned a domain. I have to do real-world stuff right now, but feel free to edit my answer into equivalent English if you like.